# Is there a way to not return the query name in a useQuery result?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

I would like useQuery to write data.queryName to the data output instead of data so that I don’t have to specify the query name whenever I call the object. For example, if I called useQuery like so:

```
const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(TRACKS)
```

then whenever I want to refer to data, I will have to write

```
data.queryName.someAttribute
```

but I want to be able to call

```
data.someAttribute
```

such that queryName is selected before we are writing to data. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't think this is a valid question, you can access attribute directly through `data.someAttribute`, [see docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query). Or you can post a sandbox link with a minimum viable example, that way we can take a closer look.

Comment: I think the confusion stems from GraphQL folks calling the query name the part after the query keyword `query QueryName {`, but OP seems to referring to the query name as the top level query field e.g. `book` in `query QueryName { book { someAttribute } }`. Is this correct?